# Hadoop 2.6.0 JobCounters always returning zero

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to get the total time spent by the map phase and by the reduce phase in a job run. So I've tried to use the *JobCounters* *MILLIS_MAPS* and *MILLI_REDUCES*, but its seems that when I try to get the value these one is always zero. Besides this, I also notice that these counters aren't printed when the job is completed successfully, which leads to my questions.

The JobCounters are in use in Hadoop 2.6.0? Were they deprecated?

If not, how can we use them correctly?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
Date startTime = new Date();
System.out.println("Job started: " + startTime);
job.waitForCompletion(true);

Date end_time = new Date();
System.out.println("Job ended: " + end_time);
System.out.println("The job took " +
            (end_time.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) /1000 + " seconds.");

Counters counters = job.getCounters();

Counter mapTime = counters.findCounter(JobCounter.MILLIS_MAPS);
System.out.println(mapTime.getDisplayName() + " : " + mapTime.getValue());

Counter reduceTime = counters.findCounter(JobCounter.MILLIS_REDUCES);
System.out.println(reduceTime.getDisplayName() + " : " +reduceTime.getValue());
```

UPDATE:
  It seems that I can only print these counters when running yarn. Any ideas how   to get them without running yarn?

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Have you seen http://diveintodata.org/2011/03/15/an-example-of-hadoop-mapreduce-counter/ ?

Comment: Yes @luliia, I've tried to show all the Counters. However, the printed Counters do not include the counters that I mentioned.